# JSON - Нужно добраться до значения

Tags: php, json, steam-web-api

Здравствуйте, есть код, который декодирует JSON страницу

```
$weaponname = $row['weaponname'];
$weaponinfo = json_decode(file_get_contents('http://steamcommunity.com/market/listings/730/'.rawurlencode($weaponname).'/render?start=0&count=1&currency=1&format=json'), true);
```

Далее идет проверка на success

```
    if ($weaponinfo['success'] == 'true'){
        print_r($weaponinfo);}
```

print_r - для просмотра массива.

И вот в чем проблема, не умею добираться до значений, а в частности **icon_url_large**, **description [0][value]**, **description [2][value]** и **description [4][value]**, **name_color**, **type**

Вот декодированный код:

```
Array
(
    [success] =&gt; 1
    [start] =&gt; 0
    [pagesize] =&gt; 1
    [total_count] =&gt; 636
    [results_html] =&gt; <div class="market_listing_table_header">
    <div class="market_listing_price_listings_block">
        <span class="market_listing_right_cell market_listing_action_buttons"></span>
        <span class="market_listing_right_cell market_listing_their_price">PRICE</span>
    </div>
    <span class="market_listing_right_cell market_listing_seller">SELLER</span>
    <div><span class="market_listing_header_namespacer"></span>NAME</div>
</div>

<div class="market_listing_row market_recent_listing_row listing_192911622659265110" id="listing_192911622659265110">

    <div class="market_listing_item_img_container">     <img id="listing_192911622659265110_image" src="http://steamcommunity-a.akamaihd.net/economy/image/-9a81dlWLwJ2UUGcVs_nsVtzdOEdtWwKGZZLQHTxDZ7I56KU0Zwwo4NUX4oFJZEHLbXH5ApeO4YmlhxYQknCRvCo04DEVlxkKgpot7HxfDhoyszJemkV4N27q4KHgvLLP7LWnn8fscMpj-qUpNymjVK1_hFrMmmhJ4-Ue1c_YgrUrgS5ybvu18K6vZ-YyWwj5HdyMRX4FA/62fx62f" srcset="http://steamcommunity-a.akamaihd.net/economy/image/-9a81dlWLwJ2UUGcVs_nsVtzdOEdtWwKGZZLQHTxDZ7I56KU0Zwwo4NUX4oFJZEHLbXH5ApeO4YmlhxYQknCRvCo04DEVlxkKgpot7HxfDhoyszJemkV4N27q4KHgvLLP7LWnn8fscMpj-qUpNymjVK1_hFrMmmhJ4-Ue1c_YgrUrgS5ybvu18K6vZ-YyWwj5HdyMRX4FA/62fx62f 1x, http://steamcommunity-a.akamaihd.net/economy/image/-9a81dlWLwJ2UUGcVs_nsVtzdOEdtWwKGZZLQHTxDZ7I56KU0Zwwo4NUX4oFJZEHLbXH5ApeO4YmlhxYQknCRvCo04DEVlxkKgpot7HxfDhoyszJemkV4N27q4KHgvLLP7LWnn8fscMpj-qUpNymjVK1_hFrMmmhJ4-Ue1c_YgrUrgS5ybvu18K6vZ-YyWwj5HdyMRX4FA/62fx62fdpx2x 2x" style="border-color: #D2D2D2;" class="market_listing_item_img" alt="">  </div>
        <div class="market_listing_price_listings_block">
                    <div class="market_listing_right_cell market_listing_action_buttons">
                                    <div class="market_listing_buy_button">
                                                    <a href="javascript:BuyMarketListing('listing', '192911622659265110', 730, '2', '5336517115')" class="btn_green_white_innerfade btn_small">
                                <span>
                                    Buy Now                             </span>
                            </a>
                                            </div>
                            </div>
                <div class="market_listing_right_cell market_listing_their_price">
            <span class="market_table_value">
                                                        <span class="market_listing_price market_listing_price_with_fee">
                        $2.80                   </span>
                    <span class="market_listing_price market_listing_price_with_publisher_fee_only">
                        $2.68                   </span>
                    <span class="market_listing_price market_listing_price_without_fee">
                        $2.44                   </span>
                                <br>
                            </span>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="market_listing_right_cell market_listing_seller">
        <span class="market_listing_owner_avatar">
            <span class="playerAvatar online">
                <img src="http://cdn.akamai.steamstatic.com/steamcommunity/public/images/avatars/aa/aaee0152a474ac8eade2e73169d0af4a01e14c2c.jpg" alt="">
            </span>
        </span>
    </div>

        <div class="market_listing_item_name_block">
        <span id="listing_192911622659265110_name" class="market_listing_item_name" style="color: #D2D2D2;">AK-47 | Blue Laminate (Factory New)</span>
        <br>
        <span class="market_listing_game_name">Counter-Strike: Global Offensive</span>
    </div>
    <div style="clear: both;"></div>
</div>

    [listinginfo] =&gt; Array
        (
            [192911622659265110] =&gt; Array
                (
                    [listingid] =&gt; 192911622659265110
                    [price] =&gt; 222
                    [fee] =&gt; 33
                    [publisher_fee_app] =&gt; 730
                    [publisher_fee_percent] =&gt; 0.10000000149011612
                    [currencyid] =&gt; 2003
                    [steam_fee] =&gt; 11
                    [publisher_fee] =&gt; 22
                    [converted_price] =&gt; 244
                    [converted_fee] =&gt; 36
                    [converted_currencyid] =&gt; 2001
                    [converted_steam_fee] =&gt; 12
                    [converted_publisher_fee] =&gt; 24
                    [converted_price_per_unit] =&gt; 244
                    [converted_fee_per_unit] =&gt; 36
                    [converted_steam_fee_per_unit] =&gt; 12
                    [converted_publisher_fee_per_unit] =&gt; 24
                    [asset] =&gt; Array
                        (
                            [currency] =&gt; 0
                            [appid] =&gt; 730
                            [contextid] =&gt; 2
                            [id] =&gt; 5336517115
                            [amount] =&gt; 1
                            [market_actions] =&gt; Array
                                (
                                    [0] =&gt; Array
                                        (
                                            [link] =&gt; steam://rungame/730/76561202255233023/+csgo_econ_action_preview%20M%listingid%A%assetid%D2470838473107308851
                                            [name] =&gt; Inspect in Game...
                                        )

                                )

                        )

                )

        )

    [assets] =&gt; Array
        (
            [730] =&gt; Array
                (
                    [2] =&gt; Array
                        (
                            [5336517115] =&gt; Array
                                (
                                    [currency] =&gt; 0
                                    [appid] =&gt; 730
                                    [contextid] =&gt; 2
                                    [id] =&gt; 5336517115
                                    [classid] =&gt; 310776531
                                    [instanceid] =&gt; 188530139
                                    [amount] =&gt; 1
                                    [status] =&gt; 2
                                    [original_amount] =&gt; 1
                                    [background_color] =&gt; 
                                    [icon_url] =&gt; -9a81dlWLwJ2UUGcVs_nsVtzdOEdtWwKGZZLQHTxDZ7I56KU0Zwwo4NUX4oFJZEHLbXH5ApeO4YmlhxYQknCRvCo04DEVlxkKgpot7HxfDhoyszJemkV4N27q4KHgvLLP7LWnn8fscMpj-qUpNymjVK1_hFrMmmhJ4-Ue1c_YgrUrgS5ybvu18K6vZ-YyWwj5HdyMRX4FA
                                    [icon_url_large] =&gt; -9a81dlWLwJ2UUGcVs_nsVtzdOEdtWwKGZZLQHTxDZ7I56KU0Zwwo4NUX4oFJZEHLbXH5ApeO4YmlhxYQknCRvCo04DEVlxkKgpot7HxfDhoyszJemkV4N27q4KHgvLLP7LWnn9u5MRjjeyPrIqtjVfh-kNvNj-iIdSSIwZsYlHR8wC_wrzr0cO7tMjImyZluyJz5WGdwUKTUQkCog
                                    [descriptions] =&gt; Array
                                        (
                                            [0] =&gt; Array
                                                (
                                                    [type] =&gt; html
                                                    [value] =&gt; Exterior: Factory New
                                                )

                                            [1] =&gt; Array
                                                (
                                                    [type] =&gt; html
                                                    [value] =&gt;  
                                                )

                                            [2] =&gt; Array
                                                (
                                                    [type] =&gt; html
                                                    [value] =&gt; Powerful and reliable, the AK-47 is one of the most popular assault rifles in the world. It is most deadly in short, controlled bursts of fire. It has been given a laminate stock.
                                                )

                                            [3] =&gt; Array
                                                (
                                                    [type] =&gt; html
                                                    [value] =&gt;  
                                                )

                                            [4] =&gt; Array
                                                (
                                                    [type] =&gt; html
                                                    [value] =&gt; The eSports 2013 Winter Collection
                                                    [color] =&gt; 9da1a9
                                                )

                                            [5] =&gt; Array
                                                (
                                                    [type] =&gt; html
                                                    [value] =&gt;  
                                                )

                                        )

                                    [tradable] =&gt; 1
                                    [actions] =&gt; Array
                                        (
                                            [0] =&gt; Array
                                                (
                                                    [link] =&gt; steam://rungame/730/76561202255233023/+csgo_econ_action_preview%20M192911622659265110A%assetid%D2470838473107308851
                                                    [name] =&gt; Inspect in Game...
                                                )

                                        )

                                    [name] =&gt; AK-47 | Blue Laminate
                                    [name_color] =&gt; D2D2D2
                                    [type] =&gt; Restricted Rifle
                                    [market_name] =&gt; AK-47 | Blue Laminate (Factory New)
                                    [market_hash_name] =&gt; AK-47 | Blue Laminate (Factory New)
                                    [market_actions] =&gt; Array
                                        (
                                            [0] =&gt; Array
                                                (
                                                    [link] =&gt; steam://rungame/730/76561202255233023/+csgo_econ_action_preview%20M192911622659265110A%assetid%D2470838473107308851
                                                    [name] =&gt; Inspect in Game...
                                                )

                                        )

                                    [commodity] =&gt; 0
                                    [market_tradable_restriction] =&gt; 7
                                    [app_icon] =&gt; http://cdn.akamai.steamstatic.com/steamcommunity/public/images/apps/730/69f7ebe2735c366c65c0b33dae00e12dc40edbe4.jpg
                                    [owner] =&gt; 0
                                )

                        )

                )

        )

    [currency] =&gt; Array
        (
        )

    [hovers] =&gt;      CreateItemHoverFromContainer( g_rgAssets, 'listing_192911622659265110_name', 730, '2', '5336517115', 1 );
        CreateItemHoverFromContainer( g_rgAssets, 'listing_192911622659265110_image', 730, '2', '5336517115', 1 );

    [app_data] =&gt; Array
        (
            [730] =&gt; Array
                (
                    [appid] =&gt; 730
                    [name] =&gt; Counter-Strike: Global Offensive
                    [icon] =&gt; http://cdn.akamai.steamstatic.com/steamcommunity/public/images/apps/730/69f7ebe2735c366c65c0b33dae00e12dc40edbe4.jpg
                    [link] =&gt; http://steamcommunity.com/app/730
                )

        )

)
```

А это без HTML, чтобы было удобнее понять:

```
Array
(
    [success] =&gt; 1
    [start] =&gt; 0
    [pagesize] =&gt; 1
    [total_count] =&gt; 636
    [results_html] =&gt; (УДАЛЕНО)
    [listinginfo] =&gt; Array
        (
            [192911622659265110] =&gt; Array
                (
                    [listingid] =&gt; 192911622659265110
                    [price] =&gt; 222
                    [fee] =&gt; 33
                    [publisher_fee_app] =&gt; 730
                    [publisher_fee_percent] =&gt; 0.10000000149011612
                    [currencyid] =&gt; 2003
                    [steam_fee] =&gt; 11
                    [publisher_fee] =&gt; 22
                    [converted_price] =&gt; 244
                    [converted_fee] =&gt; 36
                    [converted_currencyid] =&gt; 2001
                    [converted_steam_fee] =&gt; 12
                    [converted_publisher_fee] =&gt; 24
                    [converted_price_per_unit] =&gt; 244
                    [converted_fee_per_unit] =&gt; 36
                    [converted_steam_fee_per_unit] =&gt; 12
                    [converted_publisher_fee_per_unit] =&gt; 24
                    [asset] =&gt; Array
                        (
                            [currency] =&gt; 0
                            [appid] =&gt; 730
                            [contextid] =&gt; 2
                            [id] =&gt; 5336517115
                            [amount] =&gt; 1
                            [market_actions] =&gt; Array
                                (
                                    [0] =&gt; Array
                                        (
                                            [link] =&gt; steam://rungame/730/76561202255233023/+csgo_econ_action_preview%20M%listingid%A%assetid%D2470838473107308851
                                            [name] =&gt; Inspect in Game...
                                        )

                                )

                        )

                )

        )

    [assets] =&gt; Array
        (
            [730] =&gt; Array
                (
                    [2] =&gt; Array
                        (
                            [5336517115] =&gt; Array
                                (
                                    [currency] =&gt; 0
                                    [appid] =&gt; 730
                                    [contextid] =&gt; 2
                                    [id] =&gt; 5336517115
                                    [classid] =&gt; 310776531
                                    [instanceid] =&gt; 188530139
                                    [amount] =&gt; 1
                                    [status] =&gt; 2
                                    [original_amount] =&gt; 1
                                    [background_color] =&gt; 
                                    [icon_url] =&gt; -9a81dlWLwJ2UUGcVs_nsVtzdOEdtWwKGZZLQHTxDZ7I56KU0Zwwo4NUX4oFJZEHLbXH5ApeO4YmlhxYQknCRvCo04DEVlxkKgpot7HxfDhoyszJemkV4N27q4KHgvLLP7LWnn8fscMpj-qUpNymjVK1_hFrMmmhJ4-Ue1c_YgrUrgS5ybvu18K6vZ-YyWwj5HdyMRX4FA
                                    [icon_url_large] =&gt; -9a81dlWLwJ2UUGcVs_nsVtzdOEdtWwKGZZLQHTxDZ7I56KU0Zwwo4NUX4oFJZEHLbXH5ApeO4YmlhxYQknCRvCo04DEVlxkKgpot7HxfDhoyszJemkV4N27q4KHgvLLP7LWnn9u5MRjjeyPrIqtjVfh-kNvNj-iIdSSIwZsYlHR8wC_wrzr0cO7tMjImyZluyJz5WGdwUKTUQkCog
                                    [descriptions] =&gt; Array
                                        (
                                            [0] =&gt; Array
                                                (
                                                    [type] =&gt; html
                                                    [value] =&gt; Exterior: Factory New
                                                )

                                            [1] =&gt; Array
                                                (
                                                    [type] =&gt; html
                                                    [value] =&gt;  
                                                )

                                            [2] =&gt; Array
                                                (
                                                    [type] =&gt; html
                                                    [value] =&gt; Powerful and reliable, the AK-47 is one of the most popular assault rifles in the world. It is most deadly in short, controlled bursts of fire. It has been given a laminate stock.
                                                )

                                            [3] =&gt; Array
                                                (
                                                    [type] =&gt; html
                                                    [value] =&gt;  
                                                )

                                            [4] =&gt; Array
                                                (
                                                    [type] =&gt; html
                                                    [value] =&gt; The eSports 2013 Winter Collection
                                                    [color] =&gt; 9da1a9
                                                )

                                            [5] =&gt; Array
                                                (
                                                    [type] =&gt; html
                                                    [value] =&gt;  
                                                )

                                        )

                                    [tradable] =&gt; 1
                                    [actions] =&gt; Array
                                        (
                                            [0] =&gt; Array
                                                (
                                                    [link] =&gt; steam://rungame/730/76561202255233023/+csgo_econ_action_preview%20M192911622659265110A%assetid%D2470838473107308851
                                                    [name] =&gt; Inspect in Game...
                                                )

                                        )

                                    [name] =&gt; AK-47 | Blue Laminate
                                    [name_color] =&gt; D2D2D2
                                    [type] =&gt; Restricted Rifle
                                    [market_name] =&gt; AK-47 | Blue Laminate (Factory New)
                                    [market_hash_name] =&gt; AK-47 | Blue Laminate (Factory New)
                                    [market_actions] =&gt; Array
                                        (
                                            [0] =&gt; Array
                                                (
                                                    [link] =&gt; steam://rungame/730/76561202255233023/+csgo_econ_action_preview%20M192911622659265110A%assetid%D2470838473107308851
                                                    [name] =&gt; Inspect in Game...
                                                )

                                        )

                                    [commodity] =&gt; 0
                                    [market_tradable_restriction] =&gt; 7
                                    [app_icon] =&gt; http://cdn.akamai.steamstatic.com/steamcommunity/public/images/apps/730/69f7ebe2735c366c65c0b33dae00e12dc40edbe4.jpg
                                    [owner] =&gt; 0
                                )

                        )

                )

        )

    [currency] =&gt; Array
        (
        )

    [hovers] =&gt;      CreateItemHoverFromContainer( g_rgAssets, 'listing_192911622659265110_name', 730, '2', '5336517115', 1 );
        CreateItemHoverFromContainer( g_rgAssets, 'listing_192911622659265110_image', 730, '2', '5336517115', 1 );

    [app_data] =&gt; Array
        (
            [730] =&gt; Array
                (
                    [appid] =&gt; 730
                    [name] =&gt; Counter-Strike: Global Offensive
                    [icon] =&gt; http://cdn.akamai.steamstatic.com/steamcommunity/public/images/apps/730/69f7ebe2735c366c65c0b33dae00e12dc40edbe4.jpg
                    [link] =&gt; http://steamcommunity.com/app/730
                )

        )

)
```

То есть нужна помощь в указании правильного значения для переменных (**$img,$exterior,$description,$case,$color,$type**)

Comment: стрктура этого массива фиксирована? Если да, то почему нельзя `$res = ['first']['second']['third']`

Comment: Хах, а весь прикол в том, что так не выходит, и да, он не фиксированный,одно значение всегда разное, в зависимости от $weaponname, это которое **[5336517115]**

Comment: То есть я, например, пишу ['assets'] выдает Array... добавляю ['730'] уже пустота...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$weaponinfo = json_decode(file_get_contents('http://steamcommunity.com/market/listings/730/AK-47%20%7C%20Redline%20%28Field-Tested%29/render?start=0&count=1&currency=1&format=json'), true);
var_dump($weaponinfo['assets']['730']['2']['7032360339']);
```

Можно так получить значение массива не зная ключа

```
$a = reset($weaponinfo['assets']['730']['2']);
```

Ну или **foreach** или **array_search**

Comment: Последний элемент кстати меняется через какое-то время. Для второй итерации он у меня изменился на 7032370149

Comment: Да? Не замечал, а как тогда тут поступить? Кстати, var_dump выдает NULL, как раз наверное потому, что значение меняется, можно ли как-то обойти его?

Comment: Да. Я обновил свой ответ. Через **reset** возвращает первый элемент массива. Если элементов несколько. Тогда нужно перебирать их. Или преобразовать из ассоциативного в индексный. **array_values**

Comment: Да, спасибо огромное, я сделал так:
`$weaponinfo = reset($weaponsinfo['assets']['730']['2']);
    $img = $weaponinfo['icon_url_large'];
            echo '<div class="weapon">
<img src="https://steamcommunity-a.akamaihd.net/economy/image/'.$img.'">`
Причем, эта переменная случайно получилась `$weaponinfo['icon_url_large']`, забыл добавить s, смотрю, а все работает, сначала не понял, потом дошло)